# Element changed only once in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make an element 'vibrate' using JavaScript upon clicking it by repetitively changing the value of `document.getElementById("ElementID").style.left`. I change it a number of times in a particular function, but instead of moving each time I change it, it only moves at the end of the function i.e. the last time I make the change. Here is the HTML code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
        function changePosition() {
            if (document.getElementById("ElementID").style.left == "50%") {
                document.getElementById("ElementID").style.left = "52%";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("ElementID").style.left = "50%";
            }
        }

        function vibrate() {
            changePosition();
            setTimeout(changePosition, 50);
            setTimeout(changePosition, 50);
            setTimeout(changePosition, 50);
            setTimeout(changePosition, 50);
        }
    </script>
    <button id="ElementID" type="button" style="position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%;" onclick="vibrate()">Vibrate Me</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

At the end I only see the position of the button as it should have been but I can't see the transition during the change. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is kind of a cool UI idea.  Is this just an experiment, or will you vibrate the button when required form data is not present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that all timeouts will execute at the same time. Try changing to this

```
setTimeout(changePosition,100);
setTimeout(changePosition,200);
setTimeout(changePosition,300);
setTimeout(changePosition,400);
```

or

```
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
   setTimeout(changePosition,100*i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres an example using setInterval rather than timeout. Mess with the numbers and you should be able to get your desired result

http://jsbin.com/oSIXayun/4/

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<button id="ElementID" type="button" style="position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%;">Vibrate Me</button>
```

JS:

```
function changePosition() {
    if (document.getElementById("ElementID").style.left=="50%") {
        document.getElementById("ElementID").style.left="52%";
    }
    else {document.getElementById("ElementID").style.left="50%";}
}
function vibrate() {
    changePosition();
    setTimeout(changePosition,50);
    setTimeout(changePosition,100);
    setTimeout(changePosition,150);
    setTimeout(changePosition,200);
}
document.getElementById("ElementID").onclick = vibrate;
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

All the `setTimeout` calls within `vibrate()` are made at the same time. You can address this by calling `changePosition()` based on the number of vibrations you require and repeating the function using `setTimeout`.

```
(function () { 
    var vibrating = 0;

    function changePosition() {
        if (document.getElementById("ElementID").style.left == "50%") {
            document.getElementById("ElementID").style.left = "52%";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("ElementID").style.left = "50%";
        }
        if (vibrating != 0) {
            vibrating--;
            var t = setTimeout(changePosition,50);
        }
    }

    function vibrate() {
        vibrating = 4;
        changePosition();
    }

    document.getElementById('ElementID').onclick = vibrate;
})();
```